# What does 'tickety boo' mean?

Tags: meaning, british-english, slang

We had an engineer at our house the other day to check an appliance and he used the term 'tickety boo' at least three times. Clearly being British I am aware of the expression, and I also think I know what it means i.e that everything is running smoothly. But what is its origin?

Comment: You should conduct some elementary research, post your findings, and then ask questions that can help dispel any disambiguation for the listed findings. Currently you are asking people to google "tickety boo" for you.

Comment: Discussion and alleged duplication alike seem to lack [this vital connection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzVCahrtaWI) from *Merry Andrew* with Danny Kaye (1958).

Answer (score 3):

[Chambers](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=tickety%20boo&title=21st) gives the following definition:

> **tickety-boo *adj***
>   *dated Brit colloq* fine; satisfactory.
>   ETYMOLOGY: 1930s.

[Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tickety--boo?q=tickety%20boo) has

> **tickety-boo *adjective***
>   [*predic.*] *British informal, dated*
>   in good order; fine: *everything is tickety-boo*
>   Origin: 1930s: perhaps from Hindi ṭhīk hai 'all right'

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tickety-boo#English) states:

> I understand that the origin is India. In Hindi, "Tikai babu" means "It's alright, Sir." While India was governed under the British Empire, British airmen picked up the expression and it evolved into its current form. Canadian soldiers picked up the expression from their British allies during World War 2, and introduced it into Canadian jargon soon after.

On the other hand, [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tickety+boo) and [TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tickety-boo) (both referencing the same source) suggest:

> **Origin**: 1935–40; perhaps expressive alteration of the phrase *that's the ticket*.

Comment: Thanks for your considerable effort with this one. Do you think, also. that the term is conveniently alliterative, the sound replicating that of a railway engine if you say it over and over again? Tickety-boo, tickety-boo, tickety-boo! The British, the Indians and the railway system of India were, after all, locked in a romantic triangle of aspiration in the early-20th century.